# Hide element text but not child text

Tags: css

Consider this element hierarchy

```
<div>
    A
    <div>B</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to hide text `A` but not `B` with CSS? The layout should also leave no empty space where `A` would be.

What I tried:

- Setting `visibility` to `hidden` and resetting it on child leaves blank space
- Setting `font-size` to `0` on parent and resetting on child works in FF but not WebKit on iOS

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vva84/34/) for the problem

Comment: Check my answer Erick

Answer (score 6):

You may try using `visibility:collapse`:

```
body > span{
    visibility:collapse;
}
span > span {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4yfxgcms/4/)

Also this works with `visibility:hidden;`

```
body > span{
    visibility:hidden;
}
span > span {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4yfxgcms/3/)

Comment: Does this have any browser restrictions? In Opera it still leaves a white space for me (exactly where the A would have been).

Comment: The `visibility: collapse` declaration is only valid for table-cells, and works poorly even there. See http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/visibility/ for example. To quote that post: "basically: don't use this ever."

Comment: Doesn't work if you replace the `span`s with `div`s or something else.

Comment: @R.T. no it doesn't. You just ordered the nodes differently so the issue doesn't show up in the first place. Move the text before the link.

Comment: @ErikAigner:- Is it possible to give me a fiddle as I changed it and it works:- http://jsfiddle.net/Vva84/33/

Comment: @R.T.you are mixing inline and block elements. I don't think it's that hard to copy my original example to a JS fiddle, but here it is http://jsfiddle.net/Vva84/34/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Use your same concept like this

CSS:

```
     #a {
           visibility:hidden;
           font-size:0px
        }
        #b {
            visibility:visible;
            font-size:10px
        }
```

HTML:

```
 <span id="a">A
    <span id="b">B</span>
        </span>
```

## [DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/9aLpqzwo/)

## [DEMO2](http://jsbin.com/hefehupuhese/1/edit)

FOR this HTML:

```
 <div id="a">A
    <div id="b">B</div>
        </div>
```

## [DEMO UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/9aLpqzwo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think you're on the right track with the visibility stuff: it's the only property where the display doesn't override the visibility of the child element (`display: none` cannot be overridden on a child element).

Note that `visibility: collapse` is only applicable for table-cells (and works poorly even there): `visibility: hidden` is what you're after.

To counter the non-collapsing nature of visibility toggling, your could try to fiddle with absolute positioning.

Check out this demo for the basic idea: http://jsbin.com/hetis/2/edit